# Limit mouse movement to one window only

Tags: windows, windows-7, window, simulator, hud

I am trying to mimic a Head-Up Display in a racing simulator, and I want to display a semi-transperant program window (i.e. a browser window showing a java applet) which limits mouse movements to that window only.

That way I can use a USB-track pad or the like to interact with the content in the dialog screen while still interacting with the racing simulator.

My question is mainly focused on the restriction of mouse movement, is this possible in Windows 7?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ClipCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call - Make sure you undo any clipping when your window is deactivated or minimized.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I am however not developing an application, I was hoping to use a browser window or something to clip the mouse courser. Maybe I should clarify that in the post.

Comment: @John: Can you _imagine_ if web browsers and web scripts were allowed to clip the cursor? My god.

Comment: No, that's why I was looking for a Windows app that did it.